# Can Morbid be triggered after the Morbid creature is cast?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a [Deranged Outcast](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Deranged%20Outcast) and no other creatures in play, and I have an [Ulvenwald Bear](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ulvenwald%20Bear) in hand. I would like to:

1. Cast the Bear and put the Morbid trigger on the stack
2. Have the Deranged Outcast sacrifice himself while the Morbid trigger is on the stack
3. Put 4 +1/+1 counters on the Bear

Is this play possible/legal? Is there some other order of play that could achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, but not for the reason **corsiKa** states. The reason that you cannot do this is because the Ulvenwald Bear's triggered ability has an "intervening if clause." For triggered abilities with intervening if clauses, the condition is checked both when the triggered ability would be put on the stack and once again when it resolves.

> 603.4. A triggered ability may read “When/Whenever/At [trigger event], if [condition], [effect].” When the trigger event occurs, **the ability checks whether the stated condition is true. The ability triggers only if it is**; otherwise it does nothing. If the ability triggers, it checks the stated condition again as it resolves. If the condition isn’t true at that time, the ability is removed from the stack and does nothing. Note that this mirrors the check for legal targets. This rule is referred to as the “intervening ‘if’ clause” rule. (The word “if” has only its normal English meaning anywhere else in the text of a card; this rule only applies to an “if” that immediately follows a trigger condition.)

Comment: This is correct, but corsiKa's point stands: you can't put the Morbid trigger on the stack because it won't trigger. As you note in 603.4 **the ability triggers only if the condition is true** when the trigger event (enters the battlefield) occurs.

Comment: @ghoppe, it's not clear to me what corsiKa's point actually is, since I find his answer very unclear. This answer covers the relevant point: my plan fails in step 1, because the Morbid trigger never goes on the stack unless the Outcast has already died.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, no. The text on the bear states `when it enters the battlefield`. That is the only opportunity to apply such effects.

It would be different if the text said `morbid - this creature gets +4/+4 if a creature died earlier this turn`.